# Force browser not to show print dialog

Tags: windows, printing, dialog

i want to print a document from browser using window.print(). I want browser not to show standart print dialog on current machine. I have all access to system registry and settings on it. Is there way to tweak the system in this way?

ps. Excuse me for my english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this still works, but there's an ActiveX control which can do this for you (from [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/iewebdevelopment/thread/86eaeda9-c868-4d20-95b8-3b9bc2e19cc6#04781687-463f-4738-94fa-de92fba4472f))

```
<script language='VBScript'>
Sub Print()
       OLECMDID_PRINT = 6
       OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER = 2
       OLECMDEXECOPT_PROMPTUSER = 1
       call WB.ExecWB(OLECMDID_PRINT, OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER,1)
End Sub
document.write "<object ID='WB' WIDTH=0 HEIGHT=0 CLASSID='CLSID:8856F961-340A-11D0-A96B-00C04FD705A2'></object>"
</script>
```